# Single Tap Gesture recognizer is not working on UIScrollView for resignFirstResponder?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I want to use sigle tap for the first responder to resign (keyboard). When my app starts, there is an alert asking for password and when I enter into the app there is a text box and button to create a file.

When I use [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];  the button is not responding. But when I use the taps as 2 then it works. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the event is a touch up inside event. In this case, two taps might be creating one event - such that the first tap is considered the down event and the second event is the released event.

Comment: I would release the keyboard as a first responder using the done button on the keyboard. This way, when you're done typing, the pesky keyboard goes away